# Eloquent: Multiply and add columns, then order by result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a discussion board and I am creating a list of topics called 'Top' which is sorted by how 'popular' the topic is.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
SELECT ((post_count * 2) + (like_count * 4)) as popularity_score
FROM `topics`
    WHERE `deleted`=0
ORDER BY popularity_score DESC
```

How would I do this in eloquent?  I'm not having much luck with it atm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this with `DB::raw`:

```
DB::table('topics')
    ->select('id', '...', DB::raw('(post_count*2) + (like_count*4) as popularity_score'))
    ->where('deleted', '=', 0)
    ->orderBy('popularity_score', 'asc')
    ->get();
```